# Memory leak only in Release mode

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, c++-cli

I'm developing an application in VS2010 with a C# front-end that uses native C++ DLLs through C++/CLI wrappers. I have noticed a serious memory leak (or reference leak) that only happens in Release mode. In Debug mode, the memory footprint of the application is stable.

I have narrowed the source of the problem down to a video playback loop and am fairly confident at some point the video data is not being disposed of properly. However, I'm wondering what specifically I should be looking at for a leak that occurs only in Release mode.

For what it's worth, in the C++/CLI class in question I am implementing the dispose/finalize pattern as presented [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2006/04/ccli-finalize-and-dispose.html).

Comment: Wow, could someone please explain the downvotes?! Is it because I'm not sharing code. There is *a lot* of code involved in this video playback loop, at all three layers (C++, C++/CLI, C#). I was hoping someone with a good understanding of the differences between Release and Debug modes could chime in.

Comment: @Kohanz: It is sometimes (often) unclear why people downvote.  But when I read the OP, I have the feeling that you are asking people to use their psychic debugging skills to point out the memory leak (you can look at my voting record however and probably deduce that I did not downvote). The question as originally stated is basically a request (I think) for suggestions on general debugging techniques - and that type of thing can probably be googled.

Comment: Discussion of downvotes/upvotes is discouraged. But a comment explaining what's wrong is always a good idea.

Comment: @MarkWilkins Rest assured that I always Google and search SO for solutions to my problems first. You can deduce from my question-asking record that posting a question to SO is typically a last-resort. I don't see how this question differs greatly in scope/detail from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158410/memory-leaks-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 5):

If I was you I would look for calls to deallocation functions that are in an `assert` or are otherwise in `#ifdef _DEBUG/#endif` type constructs.

Comment: This is a constructive tip. Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Go through your project settings and check all runtime libraries. 
Sometimes the problem actually is not the runtime library itself that you're linking to  but the runtime library you set to ignore in the project.

According to this page of [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6wtdswk0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you have to carefully keep an eye on which library to ignore depending on which one you are using.